# Java extends and override method

Tags: jsf

I need some help with this:

I'm using a bean to logout a page with a simple method

```
public class MyBean extends LoginBean{
...
    public String doLogout () throws Exception
    {
...
    ((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).logout();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    return null;
    }
}
```

Where the bean LoginBean is extend and i override the method doLogout in MyBean(they habe the same code, basically).
But when call the button below

```
<p:commandButton action="#{myBean.doLogout()}" ajax="false" />
```

the debug go to LoginBean.doLogout()...

Why?

Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: I think you should put @Override on the method to be absolutely sure it is overriding. If it is, I'd say you should build some more

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar thanks fot the help, I try this before make the question, but isn't the point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolve the problem creating a class `MyPhaseListener` extends `PhaseListener` and override some  phases, but I don't know why I need make this...

```
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener{

    @Override
    public void afterPhase (PhaseEvent event)
    {
     ...
    }
    @Override
    public void beforePhase (PhaseEvent event)
    {
     ...
    }

}
```

If someone explain why this is necessary, I'll be grateful.